# JPA mapping issue with composite key

Tags: jpa, nhibernate-mapping, mapping, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have a below mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "auctions")
public class Auction{
.
.
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "auction")
    private List<AuctionParamValue> auctionParamValueList;
.
.
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "auction_param_values")
public class AuctionParamValue {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected AuctionParamValuePK auctionParamValuePK;

    @JoinColumn(name = "auction_param_id", referencedColumnName = "auction_param_id",updatable=false,insertable=false)
    @ManyToOne 
        private AuctionParam auctionParam;

    @JoinColumn(name = "auction_id", referencedColumnName  = "auction_id",updatable=false,insertable=false)
    @ManyToOne @MapsId("auctionId") 
        private Auction auction;
}

@Embeddable
public class AuctionParamValuePK {
    @Id 
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "auction_id")
    private long auctionId;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "auction_param_id")
    private int auctionParamId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "auction_params")    
public class AuctionParam {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "auctionParam")
    private List<AuctionTypeParam> auctionTypeParamList;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "auctionParam")
    private List<AuctionParamValue> auctionParamValueList;
 }
```

}

When I try to persist auction I am getting below error

```
 Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'auction_param_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO auction_param_values (auction_param_val, create_ts, last_updt_ts, auction_param_id, auction_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [500, 2011-01-25 20:11:01.22, 2011-01-25 20:11:01.22, null, null]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValue[auctionParamValuePK=null])
Jan 25, 2011 8:11:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'auction_param_id' cannot be null
```

Comment: Where are `auction` and `auctionParam` properties referenced by `mappedBy`?

Comment: They not mapped. How should I map them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Auction` - `AuctionParamValue` relationship you need to do this:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "auctions") 
public class Auction {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "auction")
    private List<AuctionParamValue> auctionParamValueList;
    ...
}   

@Entity @Table(name = "auction_param_values")
public class AuctionParamValue {
     @EmbeddedId
     protected AuctionParamValuePK auctionParamValuePK;

     @ManyToOne @MapsId("auctionId")
     private Auction auction;

     ...
}
```

Regarding `AuctionParam` I'm not sure what kind of relationship you want to express.

You can find a complete set of examples of *derived identities'* mappings (i.e. composite keys with foreign keys inside them) in [JPA 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317), section 2.4.1.3.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link.I am going through it now. I tried @MapsId but its giving me the same error :(

Comment: Sourabh: Wait, `auctionParamId` is `null` because you don't assign any value to it, what other behaviour do you expect. Also note that you can't use `@GeneratedValue` with derived identity.

Comment: I got it , I should populate auctionParamId myself but what about auctionId , when I persist "auction" I should get the auctionId of last inserted auction right ?

Comment: now error Can't add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`portaldemo`.`auction_param_values`, CONSTRAINT `auction_param_values_auction_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`auction_id`) REFERENCES `auctions` (`auction_id`)) INSERT INTO auction_param_values (auction_param_val, create_ts, last_updt_ts, auction_param_id, auction_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 bind => [2011-01-12 04:00:00, 2011-01-25 22:30:52.493, 2011-01-25 22:30:52.493, 1, 0]
Query:InsertObjectQuery(com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValue[auctionParamValuePK=com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValuePK[auctionId=0, auctionParamId=1])

Comment: I am not sure how I can get auction_id to be the last inserted id in the above query when I persist auction command object :(